# How to implement room to room file sharing system using socket.io and nodejs larger than 1mb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ejs, file-sharing

**I want to implement socket.io room to room file sharing system so users can send images to their respective rooms to all user can see it and I have tried using base64 encoding method to emit sender image file to specific room but it can send only approximately 700kb to 800kb file.**

`Is there any easier way of doing this and can support larger files above 1mb and it should be able to load images progressively?`

`I am using ejs template engine, nodejs, socket.io, javascript.`

`Console.log("please help me guys if you any idea about this, I tried many things but none of them are working and I have read the socket.io documentation but didn't get any clue about it`

**I have also tried binary streaming but got no luck please help me guys with some codes samples**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably find it easier for the client to upload the file to your http server with a room name and then have your http server send a message to all the other clients in the room via socket.io with a URL where the client can download the file using http.  socket.io is just not a streaming protocol, it's a packet or message-based protocol so to send large things, it has to be broken up into messages and then reassembled on the client.  This can be done, but it's just extra non-standard work that http uploads and downloads already know how to do.

Here would be the steps:

1. Client uploads file to server via http post with the room name as a field in the form.
2. Server receives uploaded file, assigns it a unique ID and stores it in a temporary location on the server on disk.
3. When file upload completes server notifies all other clients in the room via socket.io that the file is uploaded and ready for download and sends them the URL for download that has the uniqueID in it.
4. Each client sends request to download the file via http using the unique URL they received.
5. Server serves the file to each client as requested over http.
6. Server either keeps track of whether all clients have now finished downloading or just removes the file after some period of time based on timestamp of the file (to just clean up disk space) with some regular cleanup function on a recurring timer.

You can create a single route that handles all the downloads:

```
const downloadRoot = "/temp/filexfer";

app.get("/download/:id", (req, res) => {
    const fullPath = path.resolve(path.join(downloadRoot, req.params.id));
    // detect any leading . or any double .. that might jump outside
    // the downloadRoot and get to other parts of the server
    if (!fullPath.startsWith(downloadRoot)) {
         console.log(`Unsafe download request ${fullPath}`);
         res.sendStatus(500);
         return;
    } 
    res.download(fullPath);
});
```

A cleanup algorithm could look like this:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;

// run cleanup once per hour
let cleanupTimer = setInterval(async () => {
    let oneHourOld = Date.now() - oneHour;
    try {
        let files = await fsp.readdir(downloadRoot, {withFileTypes: true});
        for (let f of files) {
             if (f.isFile()) {
                 let fullName = path.join(downloadRoot, f.name);
                 let info = await fsp.stat(fullName);
                 // if file modification time is older than one hour, remove it
                 if (info.mtimeMs <= oneHourOld) {
                     fsp.unlink(fullName).catch(err => {
                         // log error, but continue
                         console.log(`Can't remove temp download file ${fullName}`, err);
                     });
                 }
             }
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    
}, oneHour);

// unref the timer so it doesn't stop node.js from exiting naturally
cleanupTimer.unref();
```

Comment: what does leading or double means?

Comment: @AshishSingh - I've rewritten that part, but the point is that you don't want to construct a path on your server with user content in it that could contain `..` or `.` because that can allow an attacker to get to other parts of your server hard drive that you don't want them to get to as in `../../../someFile`.

Comment: can you provide some sample code of sending images from client to server and server to client using socket.io in chunks this would be very helpful for me for better understanding of both methods and ```thanks a lot for helping me```.

Comment: @AshishSingh - I'm specifically recommending AGAINST sending large files in chunks using socket.io.  It's just not what the underlying transport is good at and I have not written code to do that, nor do I think it wise to spend time doing that.  Whereas http is super easy to do that with and all the infrastructure is already there.

Comment: Thanks I have implemented what you have said to me so, you can you me little more , the thing is that how can i keep track  of download status of every client in room? ```And once again thanks```

Comment: @AshishSingh - I think it would be easiest to just run a cleanup operation once an hour and remove any download files whose creation date was more than an hour old.  Otherwise, you have to create some separate server-side Map object where the download id is the key and a remaining count is the value and you count how many in the room to initialize the count and then when each download finishes, you decrement the count and when it gets to zero, you can remove the file.  But, since clients may disconnect before finishing the download, you will still need the regular cleanup operation anyway.

Comment: You know I'm very dump so, some code samples would be best .

Comment: @AshishSingh - I added an example cleanup timer function to my answer.  I have not run this code so you may have to do some debugging, but this should show you the general idea.

Comment: bro your cleanup process is too long instead of that I used this on every upload    
 ```if (uploadedFileName != null) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                fs.unlink(fullPathOfUploadedFile,function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            }, 600000 * 60);
        }```

Comment: Bro can you send me some sample code of download route , if I not use if condition which you have written on download route and how can this be manipulated to access my other server part by using my download route by the hackers

Comment: @AshishSingh - If your server restarts at any point, you will lose those timers and you'll get uploaded files accumulating over time.  My cleanup process was more robust in that case.  If you want help with the download side of things, I'd suggest you ask a new question on that topic.

Comment: immediate.unref()#
Added in: v9.7.0
Returns: <Immediate> a reference to immediate
When called, the active Immediate object will not require the Node.js event loop to remain active. If there is no other activity keeping the event loop running, the process may exit before the Immediate object's callback is invoked. Calling immediate.unref() multiple times will have no effect. **Easier explanation please**

Comment: @AshishSingh - Nodejs detects when it has nothing left to do and will exit automatically when there's nothing else to do.  If you have a `setInterval()` timer running for the cleanup process, then nodejs will never exit automatically because the timer is always running and always has something else to do.  If you want a particular timer to NOT cause nodejs to keep running on its own, then you call `.unref()` on the timer handle.  If this is a server process, it will already keep running as long as the server is still listening anyway, so probably doesn't make much difference here.

Comment: @AshishSingh - FYI, it's a little easier to read the `.unref()` doc for the timer itself: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do this sort of thing and it depends heavily on what sort of architecture you want to support.

Sending large files through socket.io or any other web-socket is fine. it does require a bunch of chopping and reassembling on your web app but it will work.

WebRTC is another way to share files of any description, and it will not burden your server in anyway which is good. (here is a tutorial on it https://ably.com/tutorials/web-rtc-file-transfer)

The issue with either of these methods is that they are transient shares, are new user to the room will not get the image, unless your server re-transmits the data again.

My suggestion would be to upload the file to s3 directly and then share a link to it that can be resolved on each of the clients. This will keep the server burden down and reduce your storage requirements in the backend server